# Unable to start Alarm Service on Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to set a repeating alarm

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "ALARM START SUCCESSFUL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

In my fragment, I am calling this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

    /* Repeating on every 20 minutes interval */
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 20, pendingIntent);
```

where `pendingIntent` is set as

```
alarmManager = (AlarmManager)(getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
Intent intent = new Intent("FIRE_ALARM");
pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), MONDAY, intent, 0);
```

Toast appears when I click set alarm button only when current time is less than timePicker time.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FIRE_ALARM"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Ok, you want a repeating alarm. But what is exactly what you want to achieve and how is your current approach different?

Comment: I want to show a toast through `alarmManager.setRepeating` according to time set on time picker

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is still unclear.

Comment: There is a time picker in my fragment. When I click set alarm, I get hour and minute from time picker. Then in my `setRepeating` command I am asking `alarmManager` to create a repeating alarm that will create toast messages. However, currently when I click "set alarm", toast shows for one time(only if set time is less than system time) and shows nothing otherwise

Comment: only once. With API target greater than 21, setrepeating will not trigger off at exact times. So you might see your toast at some time greater than 20minutes also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of API level 19 `setRepeating()` will no longer get triggered at exact times. You can do something like this instead:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static synchronized void startAlarm() {

        AlarmManager alarmManager =
            (AlarmManager) ApplicationContext.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent("FIRE_ALARM");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ApplicationContext.getContext(), 1, intent, 0);

        // ...

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, interval, pendingIntent);
        else
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, interval, pendingIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("FIRE_ALARM")) {
            // do stuff
            startAlarm();
        }
    }
}
```

and then call AlarmReceiver.startAlarm() from your main activity.